# Dúvida sobre a conexão com o banco na autenticação do laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, auth

Ola, estou com uma duvida e não consigo resolver, preciso fazer a conexão do auth do laravel 5.6 com uma base de dados ja existente, porém estou um pouco perdido, ja coloquei os drivers sql server e ja conectei com o banco no database.php, agora quero saber onde definir quais colunas e qual tabela usar para fazer a autenticação.

desde ja agradeço.

Comment: Consegue ser mais especifico? Você configurou o .env?

Comment: eu configurei o banco direto no arquivo config/database.php, eu conseguir me conectar ao banco e fazer um select, porem eu quero saber onde alterar os arquivos auth para poder especificar em qual tabela ele faz o select, entende?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o manual do Laravel, vc usa o artisan pra gerar tudo que precisa (rota, controller, view):

`php artisan make:auth`

(fonte: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#included-authenticating)

Dai pra frente vc deve conseguir ajustar sozinho pois ja tera toda a estrutura.